# Importing set of flat fields into multi-row matrix using Feed Me

Tags: craft3, matrix, plugin-feedme, import

I'm using 'Feed Me' in Craft 3 to import data. The data has 9 fields (like `full_name_child_1`, and `gender_child_1`...) and has 10 sets of them (all the way to `full_name_child_10`, etc).

I originally mirrored that setup in craft and imported everything fine... but I'd rather have that as one Matrix field with 9 fields (and 0 to 10 row) rather than 90 separate fields with a bunch of nulls.

BUT... Feed Me doesn't seem to support that. In the mapping stage, it only allows you to map to one matrix row...

[image]

Has anyone dealt with this before, or can you suggest a workaround? Maybe a way in Craft to populate a matrix with repeated sets of existing field data? Thanks!